# Is there a good word for "Assuming that"

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to replace the bolded portion with one word.

"**Assuming that** one believes Hong Kong should have democracy, is civil disobedience a just and effective means of achieving it?

The word "insofar" seems to get close, but I don't think it quite nails it. Or does it?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You could replace 'assuming that' with 'if' in this sentence, but I don't know why you would wish to.

Comment: "If" is my favorite, but "given" could work as well. The latter replacement is used more in technical writing, e.x. "Given a finite ring M, there exists a larger infinite ring N containing all the elements of M"

Comment: Yes, *Given* is the .. "most standard" way. With or without *that* afterwards; it's unnecessary, but some people prefer to include it. Another (**entirely** appropriate in this context but not all) is *Presuming…*.

Comment: The least possible change - which should matter a lot - would be simply to drop "that" in favour of "Assuming one believes…"